# If $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^3y^3z^3}\bigg(y^2z^2+9x^2z^2+25x^2y^2\bigg)=\frac{15}{x}+\frac{5}{y}+\frac{3}{z}$. Then $x,y,z$ are in ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^3y^3z^3}\bigg(y^2z^2+9x^2z^2+25x^2y^2\bigg)=\frac{15}{x}+\frac{5}{y}+\frac{3}{z},$$
then $x,y,z$ are in

$(a)$ Arithmetic Progression

$(b)$ Geometric Progression

$(c)$ Harmonic Progression

$(d)$ None of these

What I tried:

Put $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}=a,\frac{1}{y}=b,\frac{1}{z}=c$.

Then

$\displaystyle abc(a^2+9b^2+25c^2)=15a+5b+3c$

$\displaystyle a^2+9b^2+25c^2=\frac{15}{bc}+\frac{5}{ac}+\frac{3}{ab}$

Now I did not understand How can I arrange it, Please Help me

Thanks

Comment: Just an observation. The given equation has a certain symmetry $\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac9{y^2}+\dfrac{25}{z^2}=(3y)(5z)+(5z)x+x(3y)$

Comment: Pick a nontrivial AP and substitute it in. Does equality hold? Do the same for GP and HP.

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?  Please credit the original source in your question.

Comment: Any condition on $x, y, z$? If we let $p = y/x, q = z/y$, we get $(15p^4q^3 + 5p^3q^3 + 3p^3q^2)x^4 = p^2q^2 + 9q^2 + 25$. We get $x, y, z$ in terms $p, q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, let us consider the case where $x=a,y=a+d,z=a+2d$ are in arithmetic progression.
  Then, $a,d$ have to satisfy $\frac{f(a)}{a^3 (a + d)^3 (a + 2 d)^3}=0$ where $$f(a):=23 a^8 + 196 da^7 + 677d^2 a^6 + 1210d^3 a^5  + (1178d^4 - 35)a^4 + (592 d^5 - 92 d)a^3 + (120  d^6 - 74 d^2)a^2 - 12 d^3a - 4 d^4$$ We have $f(0)=-4d^4$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty}f(a)=\infty$. So, we can say that for any given $d\gt 0$, there is $a\gt 0$ such that $f(a)=0$.
- Secondly, let us consider the case where $x=a,y=ar,z=ar^2$ are in geometric progression.
  Then, $a,r$ have to satisfy $\frac{g(a)}{a^5 r^7}=0$ where $$g(a)=(15 r^7 + 5 r^6 + 3 r^5)a^4 -(r^4+ 9 r^2 + 25)$$ We can say that for any given $r\gt 0$, there is $a\gt 0$ such that $g(a)=0$.
- Thirdly, let us consider the case where $x=a,y=\frac{a}{1+da},z=\frac{a}{1+2da}$ are in harmonic progression.
  Then, $a,d$ have to satisfy $\frac{h(a)}{a^5}=0$ where $$h(a)=11 da^5 +( 23- 218d^4 )a^4  - 563d^3 a^3 - 533d^2 a^2 - 223 da  - 35$$ So, for any given $d\gt 0$, there is $a\gt 0$ such that $h(a)=0$.
- Finally, let us consider the case where $x=1,y=a,z=b$.
  Then, $a,b$ have to satisfy $\frac{i(a)}{a^3 b^3}=0$ where $$i(a)=(15 b^3 + 3b^2)a^3 + (5 b^3 - b^2 - 25)a^2 - 9 b^2$$ For $1.7<b<2$, we have $$-\sqrt b\lt 2-b<\frac 1b<\frac{b}{2b-1}\lt\frac{2b}{b+1}\lt\sqrt b\lt\frac{b+1}{2}\lt 2b-1\lt b^2\lt\frac{b}{2-b}$$ and $i(\frac 1b)\lt 0\lt i(\frac{b}{2b-1})$. So, for any given $1.7\lt b\lt 2$, there is $a$ such that $\frac 1b\lt a\lt\frac{b}{2b-1}$ and $i(a)=0$. For such $a$ and $b$, we see that $x,y,z$ are in none of these progressions.

Therefore, we can say the followings :

- There are infinitely many $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are in arithmetic progression.
- There are infinitely many $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are in geometric progression.
- There are infinitely many $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are in harmonic progression.
- There are infinitely many $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are in none of these.

---

*Comment* :

If, instead of the given equation which can be written as $x^{\color{red}{-2}}+9y^{\color{red}{-2}}+25z^{\color{red}{-2}}=xyz(\frac{15}{x}+\frac{5}{y}+\frac{3}{z})$, we are given
$x^{\color{red}2}+9y^{\color{red}2}+25z^{\color{red}2}=xyz(\frac{15}{x}+\frac{5}{y}+\frac{3}{z})$ which can be written as $(x-3y)^2+(3y-5z)^2+(5z-x)^2=0$, then we can say that $x,y,z$ are in harmonic progression.